# name of the strumming technique

Tags: guitar, technique, terminology, flamenco

I was watching the following video:

Can you please tell me the name of the strumming technique the guitarist used in the beginning of the video? I have been looking for a tutorial for the technique but cannot find it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a kind of [Rasgueado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasgueado) to me.

Comment: I have seen the rasgueado technique just there are so many variations to it that I could not recognize it... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is rasguedo, with a touch of tremolo where he plays the same note several times in succession. The rasguedo is strumming the strings with several fingers, one after the other in a sort of flicking motion.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically it is n upright thumbless rasguedo. Popular in flamenco music.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could be considered a rasgueado. However, as opposed to the rasgueados used in flamenco guitar, he seems to be hitting the strings with the inside of the fingers instead of with the nail side. In other words, the motion isn't that of a rasgueado per se (where you fling the fingers outwards), it is the motion of a tremolo played simultaneously across several strings. This creates a much smoother, softer sound that any of the flamenco rasgueados would.